# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Network Error ( Axios )

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I am using axios library to fetch some data, i am getting this error :

```
  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error
Error: Network Error
    at createError (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:62131:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:62039:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:17900:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:17655:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:17482:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:17592:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:3478:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:2384:44)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:2154:17
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/c3815ce6-c51e-4580-ad86-346e4a022da3:2346:11)
```

And my code for fetching is :

```
componentWillMount(){

        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => {
                this.state.setState({albums: response.data});
                console.log(this.state.albums);
            })
            .then(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, it's working perfectly

```
axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({albums: response.data});
                //console.log(this.state.albums);
                console.log(response);
            })
            .then(error => console.log(error));
```

The problem was in `this.state.setState({albums: response.data});`